# AttributeError: 'FlashPolicyServer' object has no attribute 'kill'

Tags: python, django, django-socketio

I get the following error as soon as I run django app along with the django-socketio app using python manage.py runserver_socketio

```
SocketIOServer running on 127.0.0.1:8001

KeyboardInterrupt
Thu Jul  6 22:04:52 2017
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_socketio-0.3.9-py2.7.egg/django_socketio/management/commands/runserver_socketio.py", line 65, in handle
   server.kill()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/server.py", line 43, in kill
   self.policy_server.kill()
 AttributeError: 'FlashPolicyServer' object has no attribute 'kill'
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio/issues/63) issue, I tried downgrading gevent-socketio and gevent and it worked.

```
pip uninstall gevent-socketio gevent
pip install gevent-socketio==0.2.1 gevent==0.13.6
```